# Rough/ballpark thermodynamics and black body temperature question

Tags: thermodynamics

This is probobly pretty basic but I got into a debate with someone and the temperature of Titan came up, and I did some quick and dirty calculations - as follows.

Titan is about 9.5 times as far from the sun as the earth is, so, per square foot, it gets about 1/90th the solar energy the earth does.

According to the Stefan-boltzmann law, heat radiates off an object at the 4th power of the temperature, so if the earth recieves 90 times the energy per square foot in energy than Titan, it makes sense that it would also, given time to let the equilibrium happen, radiate about 90 times the energy per square foot as Titan, and so it's temperature should be roughly the 4th root of 90 times Titan's temperature (about 3) and that seems roughly true.

Earth - average temp, about 288 degrees.   Titan average temp, about 94 degrees.   3 times 94 = 282. - pretty close.

Now, I know this quick and dirty calculation doesn't take into account internal heat, albedo, tides or Greenhouse, but my question is - is that roughly correct - 2 identical objects, the one that gets 90 times as much energy (or, 81 times) as the other should be three time as hot, or is that a bad way to look at it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be roughly correct.

If you want to also roughly estimate the difference that internal heat, tides and atmosphere (the Earth's) would have had, you can look at the moon, which is the same distance from Titan but has an average surface temperature of $268K$. So your error is about $20K$ for estimating earth's temperature from Titan's. $268K/3\approx 95K$ which is more accurate for Titan's temperature.